# Error deserializing the object

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service. It has a following attributes.

```
[DataMember]
public List<uttAppointmentPhoneList> AppointmentPhoneList { get; set; }

public class uttAppointmentPhoneList
{
    string _PhoneType;
    Int32 _PhoneNumber;
    bool _IsDelete;

    [DataMember]
    public string PhoneType
    {
        get { return _PhoneType; }
        set { _PhoneType = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Int32 PhoneNumber
    {
        get { return _PhoneNumber; }
        set { _PhoneNumber = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public bool IsDelete
    {
        get { return _IsDelete; }
        set { _IsDelete = value; }
    }

}
```

But I get the following error when I send a request.

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type MarshfieldClinic.Denbigh.AppointmentService.Sync.DataContracts.mydayapp. The value '3456787463' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.'. Please see InnerException for more details.

Any Ideas why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Int32 PhoneNumber`

That's totally wrong.
A phone number is a string, not a number.

This specific error is happening because most phone numbers will not fit in 32 bits.
However, you need to use a string.

Answer (score 0):

That int is larger than the maximum int value.  Use a string for the phone number.

max int value: 2,147,483,647 (source: http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-maxvalue)

3,456,787,463 > 2,147,483,647

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Int32 is too small for the value you're handling (3456787463).
Try with long and see if it works.

Or if it's a phone number you can always use string and format it later to your liking

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PhoneNumber` as informative input so using `String` and you don't require for any intensive caculation in your program