# DataContractSerializer - Input String not in correct format error

Tags: .net, wcf, datacontractserializer

Is there a way to get access to the name of the element in error (or the DataMember name defined in the DataAnnotation of the element). That does not hold the correct value during deserializing of an object via the DataContractSerializer?

For example the following DataContract and xml would generate the error found below, if run through the deserializaer. "*Input string was not in correct format*" because no value was available for a "IsRequired" element.

How can i get access to the property name "Amount" or the datamember name "Amount" (either one im not fussed) from the exception that will be raised, so that i can report the error is on the element "Amount" so that the error message i create is not so "broad"

**DataContract**

```
<DataContract(NameSpace:="http://tempuri.org/blahblah")>
Public Class [Account]
    ...
    <DataMember(IsRequired:=True, Order:=11, Name:="Amount")> Public [Amount] As Decimal
End Class
```

**XML to be passed**

```
<Account>
    ...
    <Amount></Amount>
</Account>
```

**Full error reported during serialization**

```
There was an error deserializing the object of type MyProjectName.Account. Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the thrown exception's `InnerException` (see [Error deserializing the object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12199790/54249) for an example), or maybe either exception's [`Data` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: unfortunately there is no extra detail in the Data field, and have been through all the visible property of the exception and innerexception without finding it available for use.